# how to sort and limit embeded arrays using spring data mongorepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to sort and limit embeded arrays using pagination, is that possible to acheive this using MongoRepository. Below is my json, and i am trying to get top ten notifications

```
{
  "id":"5d357ce265cb136751177aas",
  "notifications": [
    {
      "id": "5d357ce743cb133241177aaa",
      "owner": null,
      "itemId": "5d357ce743cb11254584abg",
      "type": null,
      "createdOn": "2019-07-22T03:41:05.428+00:00",
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "id": "5d357d2b43cb133241177aaf",
      "owner": null,
      "itemId": "5d35745243cb11256954abg",
      "type": null,
      "createdOn": "2019-07-22T03:41:14.367+00:00",
      "read": false
    }
  ]
}
```

i expect the output like this

```
"notifications": [
    {
      "id": "5d357d2b43cb133241177aaf",
      "owner": null,
      "itemId": "5d35745243cb11256954abg",
      "type": null,
      "createdOn": "2019-07-22T03:41:14.367+00:00",
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "id": "5d357ce743cb133241177aaa",
      "owner": null,
      "itemId": "5d357ce743cb11254584abg",
      "type": null,
      "createdOn": "2019-07-22T03:41:05.428+00:00",
      "read": false
    }

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
db.collection.update( { <query selector> }, { <update operator>: { 
"array.$.field" : value } } )
```

Comment: hi @Stian i need to retrieve top ten notifications from the first json

Comment: hey, sorry if I sound stupid. Do you want to retrieve top ten by date from a .json file with javascript ? I am abit slow today.

Comment: its ok @Stian. I  want to retrieve top ten by date from DB using mongoRepository

Comment: db.runCommand(
   {
     find: "createdon",
     filter: { rating: { $gte: 10 }, 
     sort: { date: 1 }, # 1 for ascending -1 for descending
     limit: 10
   }
) 
Sorry @dijofrancis I dont know much about mongodb, hope it can help any.